# delayed_job randomly disappearing jobs without executing them

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

Rails 3.2.8, delayed_job (3.0.3), delayed_job_active_record (0.3.3).  Using WEBrick.

I have an initializer that asynchronously populates the cache on startup:

```
MyModel.delay.get_lots_of_records
MyModel.delay.get_some_other_records
MyOtherModel.delay.get_tons_of_records
MyOtherModel.delay.get_some_other_records
```

In the development environment, this works fine, as evidenced by the delayed_job log and the cache log.

In staging, however, sometimes 1 or 2, or sometimes none of these jobs are executed.  Usually at least one, typically the same one (but not always), is executed.  If I look at the delayed_jobs table after startup, I see **all 4** jobs get written and then vanish 2 seconds later.

Per the recommendation [here](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/wiki/Common-problems#wiki-jobs_are_silently_removed_from_the_database), I have

```
# config/initializers/delayed_job_config.rb
Delayed::Worker.destroy_failed_jobs = false
```

But the jobs are still being very quickly deleted without failing or executing.

If I insert breakpoints at `Delayed::PerformableMethod.perform`, I see that method called only if the jobs are actually executed, so the problem is upstream of that.  The `destroy` method is called after `perform`, though, so I'm not sure what's going on.

I'm looking for troubleshooting recommendations or additional diagnostic actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sheepishly:  I had a worker running in another environment, pointing to the same DB, that was running the jobs concurrently with my staging environment.  This unintended consequence is a good reason to never share DB's between environments.